# What does "Go along the ground" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does "Go along the ground" mean? I couldn't find any source explaining it.

Context:

> I got to the top FIRST. I've never ever won a proper race before. I'm
>   hopeless going **along the ground**. I nearly always come last. But I
>   can fly upwards like a rocket. I spread my arms when I was all alone
>   at the top.

- A children literature. You can find that bit exactly here: https://fullenglishbooks.net/english-books/full-book-buried-alive-read-online-chapter-4

Comment: Tahnk you for the beautiful edit.

Comment: It sounds as though the speaker has been the first to reach the top of a mountain even though he/she is not a fast runner on flat ground.

Comment: Exactly! But how does "Along the ground" mean "flat ground"..?

Comment: It's literal. It means exactly what it says. There's no idiomatic sense in the phrase.

Comment: It is just contrasting climbing with walking/running "on the ground." But it does seem rather odd/awkward phrasing to me.

Comment: @DuyDuy , would you kindly provide us with additional context, please? A short description of the book, the character, or some paragraphs preceding the one you provided would be more than sufficient.

Comment: @vth You can find that bit exactly here: https://fullenglishbooks.net/english-books/full-book-buried-alive-read-online-chapter-4 It's about a running race up to the top of an mountain between the character (a kid), his mom,dad and a chubby looking friend. He won, he was so proud of it.

Comment: I'll note that "go to ground" means something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The speaker in the story is slower than the others when it comes to running on the ground but is faster than the others at *climbing up*.

**Going along the ground** is just a way of expressing the speaker's (slower) movement on a mostly horizontal (flat) surface that needs to be run along. This is in comparison to the speaker's (faster) movement on a mostly vertical surface that can be climbed.

Comment: This interpretation is correct. According to the [source provided by OP](https://fullenglishbooks.net/english-books/full-book-buried-alive-read-online-chapter-4), the character in question is climbing up an old castle.